# I am having trouble understanding the task for part B and how to prove it?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X =\mathbb N$ . Say $(k, l) ∼\text{di}(m, n)$ if and only if $k + n = l + m$.

1. Prove that $∼\text{di}$ is an equivalence relation on $X$.
2. Prove that $\{(m, 1)|m ∈ \mathbb N\} ∪ \{(1, n)|n ∈ \mathbb N, n > 1\}$ is a complete set of representatives for $∼\text{di}$.

Comment: Welcome to maths SE. Have a look at Mathjax to improve your mathematical expressions. It will be easier to read.

Comment: Does $\mathbf N$ comprise $0$ for you?

Comment: @Bernard:  I don't think it matters.  It adds some pairs to the universe, but does not change whether it is an equivalence relation or whether the given pairs form a set of representatives.  We could also replace the $1$s with some higher number without changing the result.

Comment: @RossMillikan: You're right, but I wondered whether there was a transcription error, as it is so close to the construction of $\mathbf Z$ from $\mathbf N$.

Comment: @Bernard:  I agree it is a step in the construction of $\Bbb Z$ from $\Bbb N$ but it works fine even if $\Bbb N$ does not include $0$.  You just define $(m,1)$ to be $m-1$ in $\Bbb Z$ and $(1,1)$ to be $0$ in $\Bbb Z$.  In the spirit of the end of my second paragraph, we could make the pairs be $(m,1000)$ and $(1000,n)$ for $m,n \ge 1000$ and it would work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't say it, but the relation is on ordered pairs of naturals, not on naturals.  Once you have proven that $\sim$di is an equivalence relation on $X \times X$ it separates the pairs in $X \times X$ into equivalence classes.  In part B you are expected to show that every pair in $X \times X$ is equivalent to exactly one of the given pairs.  This also requires showing that no two of the given pairs are equivalent.

For a similar but simpler problem, let our set be $\Bbb Z$, the integers, and the relation being equivalence $\bmod 5$.  Part A would ask us to show that this is an equivalence relation.  Part B might ask to show that $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is a set of representatives, so every integer is equivalent to exactly one of these.  It could also ask us to show that $\{-73,41,9,-15,1004\}$ is a set of representatives.  This is also a set of representatives, but it is harder to keep track of.

Comment: So the relation R is the set of ordered Pairs of ordered pairs?

Comment: Aren’t the set of representatives that  each element of its equivalent class has other elements in the original set that have the same equivalence class?

Comment: Yes, the relation (but it is $\sim$di) is a (not the) set of ordered pairs of ordered pairs of naturals.  I cannot understand your second question.  Given an equivalence relation, the universe is split into equivalence classes.  A set of representatives is a set that includes exactly one member of each equivalence class.